# Changing download filename of file on another server

Tags: php, javascript, post

So basically, I've got a form where user inputs a popular mp3 site URL and the script scrapes the URL for the mp3 path and offers it for download through $file.

```
if ( $_POST ) {
        $file = get_id($_POST['l']);
        print "<a href=\"$file\"> Right-Click & Save Link as...</a>";
} else {
```

$file posts back as a url such as http://mp3site.com/stream/837465297349.mp3 which accessed/downloads the file. I want to be able to change the filename being downloaded to a vanity filename, is that possible? Would I have to transfer to the file to my server, rename and them post back the link to download from my server?

Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to _save_ the file locally, but you have to read it in your script and pass it on to the client – so that you can add additional headers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-4365 But be aware that this can lead into problems with script execution time etc.

Comment: @Dominic: Passing data streams from untrusted services is a security risk. Be aware.